# Excluding third party DLLs in code coverage

Tags: code-coverage

Is there an easy way to remove third party DLLs from being scanned in code coverage? I have the following run settings.

I have assemblies like

- FooBar.FunctionApp
- FooBar.UnitTests
- FooBar.IntegrationTests

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
                <Include>
                    <ModulePath>/^(?!.*test).*foobar.*/g</ModulePath>
                </Include>
            </ModulePaths>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

For some reason it is not respecting the regex and isn't scanning anything but if I used this it would have the desired output but would also include third party DLLs like `nunit` and `fluentvalidation`.

```
            <ModulePaths>
                <Exclude>
                    <ModulePath>^.*tests\.dll$</ModulePath>
                    <!-- Add more ModulePath nodes here. -->
                </Exclude>                
            </ModulePaths>
```